# Detect if multiple variables are the same?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming

I'm setting a series of variables with: `uint32_t currentLedColor[9]`

What I'd like to check is if certain ones of those are the same.

Basically want to say `if currentLedColor[0] and currentLedColor[1] and currentLedColor[2] are equal`

How would I write that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run multiple checks. For example:

```
if (currentLedColor[0] == currentLedColor[1] && currentLedColor[0] == currentLedColor[2]) {
    // do something
}
```